# How to get the pinBlocked tag from the following SOAP XML response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

How to get the pinBlocked tag from the following SOAP XML response in PHP

This is my SOAP XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ReadCardStatusResponse xmlns="http://theapi.com"><result>1</result><errorMessage>ok</errorMessage><status><terminalID>123456789</terminalID><profileNumber>123456789</profileNumber><reference>37292141</reference><valid>true</valid><pinBlocked>true</pinBlocked><activated>true</activated><retired>false</retired><loaded>true</loaded><redeemed>true</redeemed><empty>true</empty><cancelled>false</cancelled><stopped>true</stopped><lost>false</lost><stolen>false</stolen><expired>false</expired><transactionID>blahblah</transactionID><transactionDate>2004-10-28T08:54:27</transactionDate><checksum>blahblah</checksum><resultCode>1</resultCode><resultText>ok</resultText></status></ReadCardStatusResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

the response is saved in $result

i tried

```
$result->pinBlocked;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create object of `SimpleXMLElement` with your xml as string, then register namespace for `http://theapi.com` using random prefix (in this case I'm using `a`) and then, using `xpath` get your element with previously registered prefix.

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://theapi.com');

echo (bool)$xml->xpath('//a:pinBlocked')[0];
```

For PHP 5.3.3 use this:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://theapi.com');

$item = $xml->xpath('//a:pinBlocked');

echo $item[0];
```

Comment: Hmmmm on the echo (bool)$xml->xpath('//a:pinBlocked')[0]; I get a synthax error in php

Comment: Could you give me full syntax error message ?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in suhayl.php on line 102

Comment: You're probably using PHP version below 5.4 so you can't dereference array directly, in this case do it this way: `$item = $xml->xpath('//a:pinBlocked'); echo $item[0];`

Comment: im using PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:27:09)